# Can't extract sub divs from site in java

Tags: java, html, jsoup, extract

I wanna extract data from [site](http://www.grupanya.com/istanbul/firsat/dominos-1-adet-orta-boy-pizza-menusu)

For example when i try to get Price with below code, i can't.

`deal.getDetail().setPriceElement(content.select("div#main-new div.buy-now-aligner div.buy-now-price").first());`

But i can extract data from `deal.getDetail().setPriceElement(content.select("div#main-new").first());`

I can't reach the sub divs, how could it be?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the method `first()` in the wrong way.

Look at the Jsoup API;

```
public Element first()
Get the first matched element. 

    Returns: 
    The first matched element, or null if contents is empty.
```

---

This meaning, the Element object that is returned is the first matched of your selection, in your case the first `buy-now-price` div class.

If you want the child elements of that element, (there is only one in your example URL), you can use either the `child()` method or the `children()` method.

The first method takes a parameter that is the index of the child you want, and the second method returns a collection of `Element` objects as `Elements`.

Use either that is suitable for you.

Comment: It's ok. Because 'buy-now-price' is the unique div class in website.

In fact, i extracted and record data last Friday. I didn't only extract categories column. Suddenly code returns null. 

Additionally i can extract 'deal.getDetail().setTitle(content.getElementsByTag("h1").first().text());'

Comment: I think you need to edit your first post to clarify what data you exactly want to parse from the data. What text is it on the example URL that you want the result to be? Also, you don't have to include your own code such as "getDetail()" etc. since that has no valuable relevance to your original question. Focus on the Jsoup selection that doesn't work for you.

Comment: When i watch in expression window that line document.getElementById("content"), i see it shows javascripts. But when i look the site with F12, i see directly and only divs. The problem is javascript codes shown in expression window. I can't extract subdiv from site.

Comment: It's ok. That my mistake of course. I was extracting wrong div in previous method. Thanks for effort and interest Daniel B.